# Android service with background task

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I am trying to create a service with background task. 24 hrs once the thread would start and do the process.

I have tried like this. but its not worked.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

int counter = 0;
static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000; // / 1000 = 1 second
private Timer timer = new Timer();
Home home;

private boolean isRunning = true;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Not implemented...this sample is only for starting and stopping
    // services.
    // Service binding will be covered in another tutorial
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    // Announcement about starting
    Toast.makeText(this, "Starting the Demo Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();

    // Start a Background thread
    isRunning = true;
    // Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new BackgroundThread());
    BackgroundThread();

    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Stop the Background thread
    isRunning = false;

    // Announcement about stopping
    Toast.makeText(this, "Stopping the Demo Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}

private void BackgroundThread() {

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            String month = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
            String year = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            String day = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            String months = null;
            if (month.startsWith("0") || month.startsWith("1")) {
                months = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
                home.loadCalender(months);
            } else {
                months = year + "-" + "0" + month + "-" + day;
                home.loadCalender(months);
            }

        }
    }, 0, UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    /*
     * counter = 0; while(isRunning) { System.out.println(""+counter++);
     * //Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
     * 
     * }
     */

    System.out.println("Background Thread is finished.........");
}
```

}

In my main activity, i have started the Service...
plz help me to do this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use `AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to schedule your alarm to occur once per day, using `setRepeating()` (or perhaps `setInexactRepeating()`. Please do not waste the user's RAM trying to have a service running all of the time watching the clock tick.

Comment: how to use setInexactRepecting()?...If you don mine, can you plz send me some piece of code

Comment: @joyhelina: "how to use setInexactRepecting()?" -- it is a Java method, that you call on an instance of `AlarmManager`, which you get via a call to `getSystemService()` on some `Context`, like your `Activity.